# Create an email reminder with related items based on criteria

Tags: visualforce, process-builder

I am trying to understand the most efficient way of going about implementing the following scenario. Any links or guidance will be much appreciated!

Scenario

1. There are two related objects Projects and Milestones (A project can have multiple milestones). Some milestones are internal and others are external
2. There are also contacts associated with the Project (as another relationship)
3. I would like to schedule an email to go out to the list of contacts each week with the list of milestones for the project where the milestone has a tick of Publicly Available?

I have completed 1 and 2 but I cannot achieve 3. I am looking for advice on how to get to this using the Process Builder / VisualForce (or anything that works)